# How to integrate Adobe Flash Media Server into Asp.Net application to record audio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash-media-server

I would like to try to create an Asp.Net C# application to record audio online using Adobe Flash Media Server. Could you please tell if it is doable, and suggest what I could start with?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options to you:

1. [Microphone access in Silverlight via Flash and JavaScript](http://russellgreenspan.blogspot.com/2009/01/microphone-access-in-silverlight-via.html)
2. [Accessing Web Camera and Microphone](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-videos/access-web-camera-microphone/)
3. [Audio recorder Silverlight 4 sample](http://blog.ondrejsv.com/post/Audio-recorder-Silverlight-4-sample.aspx)

Sorry, that this is not a Adobe Flash Media Server, but I hope it will be helpful for doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this.